# Eliminar window.location.href JavaScript

Tags: javascript

No soy programador, pero hay alguna forma de borrar `window.location.href` o cambiar lo por otra `url` que uno desee.

```
var URLactual = window.location.href;
```

Answer (score 2):

Que quieres lograr por que lo mas logico es cambiar esto

```
var URLactual = window.location.href;
```

por esto:

```
var URLactual = "http://www.tupagina.com/";
```

Si esa es tu duda

Comment: hola amigo, gracias por responder, lo que quiero es cambiar mi url actual por otra( otro dominio) o destruirla como si no hubiera

Comment: 'var URLactual = " "; ' con esto le des un valor nulo a la variable "URLactual"

Comment: asi no me funciona, lo que quiero hacer es poner un elemento de otra web con un iframe, pero tiene protección de dominio, la idea era eliminar la url de ref y cambiarla por otra

Comment: Lamento decirte que lo que buscas no esta en nada relacionado con la pregunta que planteas en este foro. por lo que te daré el consejo formula otra pregunta donde expliques bien lo que buscas añadiendo ti código par entender claramente lo que pretendes .